# How to regex two sets of data

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have text that contains a description of my data and ends with two sets of data:

```
LONG TEXT - TAGS:(Array of TAGS) - URL
```

I need to parse this text and structure my data.

My idea was to have something like:

```
a="LONG TEXT. Tags:[ex1,ex2,ex3]"
```

and use `a = a.partition("Tags:")` (`partition` splits the text on arg) so that I get the long text on `a[0]` and the tags on `a[2]`, which I then split to get all individual tags. This can be a problem if `"Tags:"` is in `LONG TEXT`, but I can make `Tags:` unique to make it work.

I'm having trouble on how I should store the URL. I'm guessing that partitioning the string on URL could also work, but I believe there is a better way to do this in regex that would be more accommodating for the data. How should I structure my data in a way that will allow me to retrieve them as they are stored in text?

UPDATE: I can tell my users to structure their data in a certain way, but it needs to be easy. For output, I just need the text, an array of strings, and a url.

So for example, I can tell my users to input this:

```
"This is a long text, which is the original description which I have to get and 
store as text in my database.

TAGS:[Tag1,Tag 2]
URL:http://google.com"
```

or I could tell them to structure it as YAML format. But I'm aiming for simplicity here.

If say I work with the input above, what is the best way to regex it to get:

```
"This is a long text, which is the original description which I have to get and 
store as text in my database."

array of "Tag1", "Tag 2"

"http://google.com"
```

Comment: I don't know why you are having all this mess. A standard way to keep structured data as text is to convert it into YAML format.

Comment: @sawa indeed but I would like to impose the least amount of structure for the people who will write the data (they're not very technical) and no, I can't structure the form as they just input it in one text box from another site I don't control.

Comment: Post the actual input and output formats, especially since you say you don't control the input format. --Plus, you can't reliably parse unstructured text; what do you plan to do with non-conformant inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

The *best* thing to do in your case is give your users a simple (but well-commented) template that they can edit, and have them paste [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) into the free-form text field. YAML is pretty user-friendly, and is meant to be hand-editable. The YAML can then be parsed easily into a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) for use in your application.

### Sample YAML Template

The following is a basic example of the YAML markup with *description*, *tags*, and *url* defined as hash keys. You can see how easy it would be for users to modify, as long as they pay attention to indenting for continued lines.

```
:description: This is a long text, which is the original description
  which I have to get and store as text in my database.
:tags:
  - tag1
  - tag2
  - tag3
:url: http://example.com
```

Note that the array data for the tags is indented for readability. However, Ruby's YAML parser would be just as happy if the tags weren't indented in this particular case.

You could also make liberal use of comments in your text template to offer YAML formatting help, or to document valid keys or values. For example:

```
# Make sure to indent descriptions longer than one line!
:description: This is a long text, which is the original description
  which I have to get and store as text in my database.
# Valid tag names include tag1..tag9, and the word "quux."
:tags:
  - tag1
  - tag2
  - tag3
# Use a full URI with scheme, and not just a domain name.
:url: http://example.com
```

### Parse the YAML

You use [YAML#load](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load) or [YAML#load_file](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_file) to parse YAML into Ruby objects. For example:

```
require 'yaml'

data1 = YAML.load string_or_here_document
data2 = YAML.load_file '/path/to/yaml/file'
```

### YAML Input Parsed to Ruby Hash

Given the YAML above, you will get the following Hash object after properly parsing your input string or file:

```
{:description=>
  "This is a long text, which is the original description which I have to get and store as text in my database.",
 :tags=>["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
 :url=>"http://example.com"}
```

You can then access the values like any other Hash object. For example:

```
data1[:url]
#=> "http://example.com"

data2[:tags]
#=> ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```